# Export and import macro files in TeXstudio

Tags: macros, texstudio

Lately, TeXstudio made changes to how macros and their shortcuts are handled. Before the change, macros were defined in the macros menu, and then shortcuts could be assigned under *Options > Configure TeXstudio > Shortcuts*. Now, one can assign shortcuts directly in the macros menu, and also export and import macro files from the same menu.

When I click on *Export*, I choose a folder and save the file, but when I try to import, no macro files are recognized. From the menu it seems the expected extension is `.txs`, but it doesn't work. What is the correct file extension to be used for macro files?

Comment: the expected extension is `.txsMacro`. isn't that the file extension you get when you export your macros? which OS are you on by the way?

Comment: I'm using Solus (linux), and it doesn't give an extension automatically. But this extension works and answers my question, thanks. If need be, you can make an answer of it and I'll mark it as solved for others' use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expected extension for the macro files is `.txsMacro`. In case this changes in the future, you may take reference from the files in the [online repository](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio-macro).